# Putting html attribute in the output with css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, styling

Is it possible to visually display html attributes which normally only reside in the source code, in the output of html, anchored to the element they are grouped with?

For example, here is some css which visually groups some `<span></span>` tags in rounded rectangles for clarity:

```
span{
    display:inline-block;
}

span:first-child{
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:15px;
    padding:10px;
}
span:last-child{
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:15px;
    padding:10px;
}

<span class="complete-sentence">She <span class="verb">loves</span> him a <span>lot</span>.</span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ycpw4tzz/ <-- What happens currently.

Two of the span tags have classes (global attributes) of "subject" and "verb". I want to somehow get the output display to look like this instead of what it does currently.

[image]

Comment: sure, I just need a working method I don't care what technology is used to achieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't try to use something which wasn't intended for that kind of use. Use `data-*` attributes instead.

```
<span data-type="complete-sentence">
    She <span data-type="verb">loves</span> him a <span>lot</span>.
</span>
```

Now, I've targeted the spans, which have `data-type` and using `content` attribute with `attr`, along with pseudo-selector `:before` (you can use `:after` too, if you want) applying style to them.

```
span[data-type]:before {
   content: attr(data-type) " | ";
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xa3apsdc/8)
(Also note that if you're using `:after` make it `content: " | " attr(data-type);`)

Also, user @bryc has provided an example of how you had wanted it in your image example. Do take a look at it [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xa3apsdc/10/)

Comment: The visual effect you use is indeed cleaner, but I'm trying to avoid having to hardcode each tag, for example:

what if you have <span class="tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4">She</span>

and hundreds of other <span>'s with other tags, hardcoding them all is tedious, it's better if it works for any tag without being defined in the css manually

Comment: @Gallaxhar I've removed the hard coding part.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xa3apsdc/3/
here is what I mean, it breaks if the parent tag isn't complete-sentence, also complete-sentence itself should be before a | but not sure how to do that since it's the identifier here.

currently you'd have to make a new css line for each parent tag

Comment: @Gallaxhar okay. Now, I have targeted only those which have that attribute without affecting others.

Comment: I'm not sure about the data-type attribute either, instead of "class", because it doesn't seem to allow multiple tags like <span class="tag1 tag2">text</span>

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xa3apsdc/5/ Works fine. Also if you want to keep using `class` instead of `data-type` you can use it, I just advise against it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74785/discussion-between-gallaxhar-and-amit-joki).

Comment: In chat, Amit Joki has solved this on revision 8 of that fiddle, I'm accepting the answer in anticipation he will update the demo link in his response, if not it is here http://jsfiddle.net/xa3apsdc/8/

Comment: @bryc can I include it in my answer with attribution?